# Is there a way to check if my username (creator name) of my app for Google Play is already used

Tags: android, google-play

You know when you go to the google play store,and you click on any app, just below the name of the app there is the name of the creator/company of the app.

Is there a way to check if the name that i am **ABOUT** to use for the creator of the app that i am **ABOUT** to publish is already used.

Now,i have never published a game in google play before so my apologies if the question is dumb or already asked.

Comment: Trying if https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=YourPotentialNameGoesHere leads anywhere(?)

Comment: Google will probably tell you if you can't use the name.

Comment: Thx Markus. That might be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- go to the Google Play web store at play.google.com
- click on apps
- click on any app
- click on the developer name for that app

This will take you to a URL something like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=WhatsApp+Inc.` (for WhatsApp).
Change the URL to whatever it was you wanted to search for.